# How should we clean up and disambiguate the [word] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The wiki excerpt for [word](/questions/tagged/word) (1144 questions) states:

> The `word` tag is used for referencing the Word word processing
>   application from Microsoft. If your question is about VBA then also
>   tag it VBA.

The wiki excerpt for [msword](/questions/tagged/msword) (1667 questions) states:

> Microsoft Word is a non-free commercial word processor designed by Microsoft.

There are currently plenty of uses of [word](/questions/tagged/word) that don't have anything to do with Microsoft Word:

- [How do I utilize hashtables to hold words and frequency of use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910084/)
- [Pick a Random word from text file in Php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908801/)
- [How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/)
- [Regular expression String replacement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847344/)

However I'm not sure that in these cases the tag is always meaningful.

It seems to me that there are two possible courses of action here:

1. Retag the [word](/questions/tagged/word) questions relating to Microsoft Word to [msword](/questions/tagged/msword), and edit the [word](/questions/tagged/word) wiki to indicate that [msword](/questions/tagged/msword) should be used instead for such questions.
2. Retag the [word](/questions/tagged/word) questions that don't relate to Microsoft Word to something else, then make [word](/questions/tagged/word) a synonym for [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word).

Which course of action should we take?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way would be to have `msword` tags for anything relating to Microsoft Word, and actually scrap the `word` tag as it's too ambiguous to be useful for anything, the word "word" would be better of in the title so it can be read in some context.