# Tag synonym request: [word] and [msword]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Both [word](/questions/tagged/word) and [msword](/questions/tagged/msword) tags are used for Microsoft Word questions - should/could they be "merged" or marked as synonyms?

Comment: "word" is also a unit of memory in computer programming, isn't it?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I updated the tag wiki.

Comment: @Bill: good point- I didn't think of that one. I guess I just read the wiki and saw that a vast majority of [word] tagged questions were related to Microsoft Word, so I thought I'd make the request. So in general you would you say that it is better to re-work a tag's wiki to conform to all(or most) possible uses for the tag rather than to re-tag those questions that don't conform to the wiki? I guess this is why tag suggestions require 2500 rep, so noobs like me can't throw a wrench into things :)

Comment: @JackieChiles Either approach is okay.  I favor retagging when appropriate because we really do want tags to have only one meaning if they can.  Reworking the tag wiki is fine when we need to, but in this case I think most of the questions tagged `word` should be retagged to `msword` to disambiguate.  The real problem here is the synonym request.  Synonyms should only be created when two tags mean *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110517/how-should-we-clean-up-and-disambiguate-the-word-tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[word](/questions/tagged/word) does not always relate to Microsoft's Word as seen in questions like:

- [Matching words in ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8540137/561731)
- [Matching words after a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8488444/561731)
- [What algorithms are used for seaching subwords in words?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8456542/561731)
- [Match search word accuracy possibly using the Levenshtein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8394462/561731)
- ... you get the point ...

I would say we should **modify the tag wiki** for [word](/questions/tagged/word) as to not associate it definitively with [msword](/questions/tagged/msword) (which I just did).

Comment: "word" is arguably not much of a useful tag outside of MS Word though. The linked question might be better off with the "string" tag, for example.

Comment: @Toomai true. see my update.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that one. I'd say that that's the exception to the rule though- could a better option be to re-tag such questions as [string] or similar? I'm pretty new to tag issues (and SO in general), so I'm not sure which approach is more appropriate.